# Bazel conditional compilation

Tags: c++, bazel

I am developing an OpenGL wrapper library and as part of it I want to provide a simple viewer for the users. I would like to:

- have a Qt based viewer if the user has Qt installed on their system (yes, this is non-hermetic, but Qt is big)
- have a fallback GLFW viewer with GLFW being built along with the project

In CMake I could just use `find_package` macro and only compile the Qt-related part if Qt was actually found. I can't find the same functionality in Bazel. Is it at all possible or am I thinking about the problem in the wrong way?

So the general question is: is it possible to conditionally compile a package in Bazel, e.g. based on the fact if a header file was found on the system?